# Handle bars is not compiling

Tags: handlebars.js

I am using MAC machine.  I have installed Handlebars.  But unfortunately when I compiling my handlebars file it's output is not sending to the destination file.  Destination file remains unchanged.  Please help me out to resolve this problem

PS: I have tried both the way of installing handlebars using bover and npm nothing works.

Comment: Please add your errors so that people may help you

Comment: @ChristopheThiry I am not getting any error that's the problem :( I am sure there is no compilation problem.  I have compiled the code in some other lap, that works fine. It was causing trouble only in my lap